# Authorize attribute hides endpoint in ASP.NET Core 2.0 + IdentityCore 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

There is strange behaviour when I add AuthorizeAttribute to my simple ASP.NET core 2.0 + IdentityCore application. Nothing complex, just scaffolded standard reactjs template and added Identity.
Here is identity service registration:

```
services.AddSurveyApplicationDbContext(Configuration)
                .AddEntityFrameworkMySql();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = AuthorizationConfiguration.MinimumPasswordLength;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SurveyApplicationContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation();
```

Configure method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.MapWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        });
```

And endpoint:

```
[Route("api/surveys")]
public class SurveyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISurveyService _surveyService;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public SurveyController(ISurveyService surveyService, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this._surveyService = surveyService;
        this._userManager = userManager;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSurvey([FromBody] SurveyCreateDto surveyModel)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
            return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        var user = await this._userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);

        if (user == null)
            return this.Forbid();

        var result = this._surveyService.Create(surveyModel, user.Id);

        return this.Ok(result);
    }
}
```

It keeps returning SpaFallbackRoute. Without Authorize it works fine(except User property on controller has empty claims).

EDIT: user is signed in, requests to this endpoint contains identity cookie.

What am I doing wrong?